# Remove elements from first cell array according to another

Tags: arrays, matlab, cell-array

I've two cell arrays. I need to remove elemtents from the first cell array according to another:

```
C = {'A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4', 'A5', 'A6'}

B = { 'A2','A5'};
```

I want to get this result:

```
C = {'A1', 'A3', 'A4', 'A6'}
```

I tried this but doesn't work

```
C = A(~find(A, B));
```

Comment: Plese check the documentation for `find`: "Find indices and values of nonzero elements".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

find function takes only one argument and returns indexes only of True-values(non-zero for numeric or nonempty for cell-array).

For your purpose look at [setdiff](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/setdiff.html) function:

```
C = setdiff(A,B)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
C = {'A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4', 'A5', 'A6'};
B = { 'A2','A5'};
```

You need the `ismember` function for cell arrays:

```
>> ismember(C, B)
ans =
    0   1   0   0   1   0
```

So this we invert and find:

```
C(find(~ismember(C, B)))
```